# What is the best practice to return List of data from public api inside class library?

Tags: c#

I have a class library which contains a method returning List to the clients (mvc,console app etc...).

Now while I was reading [Guidelines for Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections), I came to know about below point:

> X DO NOT use ArrayList or `List<T>` in public APIs.

Currently the client which is consuming my class library api is MVC which just loops on it and perform some string.format on some properties from `List<Statistics>` but do not change anything on original list.

I have thought of considering `IEnumerable<Statistics>` but then client can also cast it to List and then manipulate it and same goes with IReadOnlyList also.

MSDN design guidelines does not state that if not `ArrayList` or `List<T>` then what should be the appropriate COLLECTION for return List of something for public API?

This is my base class which is exposed to client :

```
public abstract class BaseManager
{
    //Other shared code
    public abstract List<Statistics> GetStatistics();
}

public class Manager1 : BaseManager
{
    public override List<Statistics> GetStatistics()
    {
        var stats = new List<Statistics>();
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        return stats;
    }
}
```

Comment: The guidelines explain in which scenario / under which circumstances you shouldn't rely on/use List<T> in an API. If your particular scenario is not such a or similiar scenario - that is, it is okay for the returned list to be manipulated by the callee the list is returned to without the API implementation caring about --, then it is no problem returning a list. However, if your API relies on the goodwill of the callee to be nice and not manipulate the list, then your API has a problem/weakness, and you should rather return an unmodifiable read-only collection/list.

Comment: @elgonzo 
The statistics is prepared by my class library method only and obviously i do not want statistics data to be manipulated by clients.They should
only be able to read it and nothing else

Comment: Then don't return a list. Return an unmodifiable read-only collection/list. Don't let your API rely on the goodwill / correct behavior of the caller when it can enforce correct behavior...

Comment: @elgonzo I have updated my question how i return List<statistics> so could you please tell me how do i return read-only collection which clients can read only and they cannot cast it in order to manipulate it?

Comment: There is literally a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Just look into the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.1 (this is not the only read-only collection type provided by the framework/core libraries; there some more geared towards particular application scenarios)

Comment: Please always proof-read your posts. Code inside angle brackets such as `This<That>` needs to be in pre-formatting, otherwise the `<That>` will disappear. I have repaired several examples of this in your post.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, you want to expose to your clients as little as possible.
You also don't want to tie them to a specific implementation if you have an interface that guarantees the contract you allow them.

So, in this spirit -

If you want your client to only be able to read the data returned using a `foreach` loop, then return an [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).
If you want your clients to have access to the `count` property, return an [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).
If you want your client to be able to access a specific part of the data based on it's index, than return an [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Please note that `IReadOnlyList<T>` inherits the `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and this interface inherits the `IEnumerable<T>` - so all of these options will allow the usage of `foreach`, the last two will allow the usage of `count` (as a property), and the last one will allow the usage of an indexer.

Also, please note that your underlying type can still be a `List` as it implements the `IReadOnlyList<T>` and therefor all other interfaces I've mentioned.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the `ReadOnly` in this case does not mean that all the members held by the collection are immutable - you can still change the properties of them (assuming they are mutable types) - but the collection itself being immutable - you can't add or remove items to / from it.

**Update**
Following your comment:
If the `IEnumerable<T>` is a list you can down-cast it:

```
IEnumerable<int> myIEnum = new List<int>(); 
var myList = (List<int>)myIEnum;
```

But the `ToList()` extension method only creates a list that is a copy of the original `IEnumerable<T>`.

If your base class would be:

```
public abstract class BaseManager
{
    //Other shared code
    public abstract IEnumerable<Statistics> GetStatistics();
}
```

The derived classes can still use a list inside the method, but will return it as an `IEnumerable<Statistics>`:

```
public class Manager1 : BaseManager
{
    public override IEnumerable<Statistics> GetStatistics()
    {
        var stats = new List<Statistics>();
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        return stats;
    }
}
```

If you want to actually create an `IEnumerable` that can't be down-cast to a list you can always do this:

```
    public override IEnumerable<Statistics> GetStatistics()
    {
        var stats = new List<Statistics>();
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });
        stats.Add(new Statistics { .... });

        foreach(var stat in stats)
        {
            yield return stat;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But as i have mention in the question that if i will return  IEnumerable<Statistics> then client can still cast it to List<Statistics> and manipulate it.I have updated my question how i return List<statistics>

Comment: You can also Create a list and then use the `.AsEnumerable()` extension method.

Comment: @EluciusFTW You could but it wouldn't help... [See a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/BMMXC62112). You can also see the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) of Enumerable.cs and see that `AsEnumerable` simply returns the same object it gets - it takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and returns an `IEnumerable<T>` - upcasting if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with .Net, you may notice there are a lot class with the name of `_______Collection`. They match the conditions in the article, so I think they are what the guideline recommends.

Such as:

- System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
- System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection
- System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.KeyCollection

So what they suggest are

- Create one like `StatisticsCollection`
- Implement a collection interface like `ICollection<Statistics>`

Comment: So are you saying that Statistics class should implement ICollection interface like this : public class Statistics : ICollection<Statistics> ??

Comment: StatisticsCollection class implement ICollection interface

Comment: But then in that case I have to implement all the members of ICollection interface right?

Comment: Yes. If you think most of the members are not in use then choose another interface. The word "public APIs" in that article I guess means public to end users. So if the APIs are used by yourself (or the team), then it's not necessary to follow the guidelines, I think it's for a production released to the public.